# Match all tabs only between <code></code>

Tags: php, regex

#### Sample Text

```
    Hello
    World

<pre><code>&lt;VirtualHost *:80&gt;
    ServerAdmin abc@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot &quot;C:\wamp\www\abc\public&quot;
    ServerName abc.local
    ErrorLog &quot;logs/abc.local-error.log&quot;
    CustomLog &quot;logs/abc.local-access.log&quot; common
&lt;/VirtualHost&gt;
</code></pre>

<pre><code>&lt;VirtualHost *:80&gt;
    ServerAdmin abc@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot &quot;C:\wamp\www\abc\public&quot;
    ServerName abc.local
    ErrorLog &quot;logs/abc.local-error.log&quot;
    CustomLog &quot;logs/abc.local-access.log&quot; common
&lt;/VirtualHost&gt;
</code></pre>

    Hello
    World
```

I would like to match all tabs only between `<code></code>`, I have tried using `/(<code>)*([\t])+/g`, but it still matches all tabs (everywhere), I intend to replace those tabs with 2 spaces later

Please guide or hint me with some regex, thanks

Comment: Your attempt matches all tabs because `(<code>)*` matches *zero* or more matches. But you cannot get this to work anyway -- it needs both a lookbehind and a lookahead of indeterminate length. Try a non-regex based solution, or single out the code blocks and do a global replace on them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, First match anything between code

```
$txt='<code>test</code>';

  $re1='(<code>)';  # Tag 1
  $re2='.*?';   # Non-greedy match on filler
  $re3='(<\\/code>)';   # Tag 2

  if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1.$re2.$re3."/is", $txt, $matches))
  {
      $tag1=$matches[1][0];
      $tag2=$matches[2][0];
      print "($tag1) ($tag2) \n";
  }
```

Then on this result, use your reg expression

Comment: With `$re1` empty, how is it supposed to match text between 2 code tags? Anyway, your code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: that was a mistake, fixed now

Comment: Instead of capturing the tags, I think you code should capture the content between the tags instead. `'#<code>(.*?)</code>#'`. And the replacement can be done directly with preg_replace_callback

Comment: @nhahtdh, thanks I had done this using what you suggested, I thought I could do it at once using regex.

Comment: @Kongthap: Do post your answer here. You can answer your own question, and accept your own answer.